# jQuery Can't Figure out Remove Class - Add Class

Tags: jquery, addclass

Hoping someone can see the error(s) in my code.

Scenario: Check database to see if sname exists. If it does, return "Screen Name is Already Taken" else return "Screen Name is Available".

The result is returning but the removeClass/addClass is not working as desired.

```
function ChkScrNmAvblty(sname) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/checkScreenName.asp',
        data: 'sname=' + sname,
        success: function(data) {

            $("#scaResult").html(data);

            if (data == "Screen Name is Already Taken") {
                $('#scaResult').removeClass('grn').addClass('red');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you console.info "data" to see if it really is what you think it is? No tags, or extra space, or anything. Does it work if you remove the "if" altogether?

Comment: I'll second this..try remove if statement and check if it work.

Comment: I removed the "if" statement with no change in results. Not sure how to do the console thing

Comment: @user1505054, after this line, do `alert(data)` or `console.log(data)` and see what value `data` has..

Comment: put a console.log('I am in success') in the top of the success method and check the console to ensure if success callback is being called or not